# iCal Calendar with option to confirm participation through URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, calendar, icalendar

I recently tried exploring iCal.NET (https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net) library to create event Calendar in my application that I can send to my clients through email.

I wanted to know that is it possible to have a link in calendar that points to a page on my website and allow recipient of the calendar to confirm their participation in the event?